# Set random color on TextView field inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, random

So basically, this is my simple_adapter_view, which i import to the listView.
I have TextView(letter),TextView(name&surname) and ImageView(send image)
I have 5 contacts in my list, and i need to change BackgroundColor of the TextView(letter) only. It has to be random for each of my 5 contacts, every time i run the app. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating a variable for each color, and assign them values using the random number generator, then create a variable of the type Color and assign the previous variables to this one. Now you can use this Color variable to change the BackgroundColor.

Comment: I would send you pics, but for some reason i cant. I just started with Android Studio and i'm really confused...I need this badly for my project,tho. You can email me if u want to help me, freakincage83@gmail.com , thanks in advance ^^